# REG: Split data on CRLF and Length of 10 characters(SQL,PL/SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, split

Oracle Database 11g R2 11.2.0.1 SE1

Consider the below table Address which has 3 rows

**ROW1**: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaCRLFbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbCRLFcccccccccccccccCRLFddddd
**ROW2**: eeeeCRLFffffffffffffgggggggghCRLF
**ROW3**: iiCRLFjjjjjjjjjjkkkCRLF

I need to split the string based on the below conditions
**Condition 1**: Split string up-to CRLF.
**Condition 2**: If length of the splitted string is greater than 10, then split that string by length of 10 characters.

**Note**: The length of a data is not fixed.

RESULT:-
**ADDRESS**
**ROW1**: aaaaaaaaaa
                    aaaaaaaaaa
              aaaaaCRLF
                    bbbbbbbbbb
                    bbbbbbbbbb
                    bbbbbbbbbb
                    bbCRLF
                    cccccccccc
                    cccccCRLF
                    ddddd
**ROW2**: eeeeCRLF
                    ffffffffff
                    ffgggggggg
                    hCRLF
**ROW3**: iiCRLF
                    jjjjjjjjjj
                    kkkCRLF

Comment: What happens for `aaaaaaaaCRLF` (length 12)?

Comment: Try the methods demonstrated here http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/category/oracle-delimited-string-manipulation/

Comment: LalitKumarB Your blog is awesome, but my issue is i need to split data both on length as well as Carriage Return & Line feed i.e CRLF.

Comment: "It is (length 10)" - only if you mean `CRLF` = `ascii(13)||ascii(10)`, which is not at all clear from your post. If you want our help then you need to give us precise details. Anyway, your response misses the point, so let me rephrase Tomalak's question. What happens for `'aaaaaaaaaa'||ascii(13)||ascii(10)` (length 12)? Or `'aaaaaaaaa'||ascii(13)||ascii(10)` (length 11)?

Comment: @user1117418 I wish if I could help you. But, it is not clear what you want. Could you please edit your question and explain the rules. Also, use **CTRL+K** to format the code instead of making it bold. I would help you for sure, given that you too help me to understand your requirement :-)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on a technique from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29338715/4311

First we will set up your sample data in our CTE named `data`.  Then the query splits this text into rows based on the occurrences of CRLF which gives us `data2`.

Then we take and add a CRLF every 10 characters in our resulting strings which gives us `data3`.  And finally we repeat the original process again to split the text into rows based on CRLF which yields `data4`.

```
with data as
(select 'row1' rowval, 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' || chr(13) || chr(10) || 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb' || chr(13) || chr(10) || 'ccccccccccccccc' || chr(13) || chr(10) || 'ddddd' txt from dual union all
 select 'row2' rowval, 'eeee' || chr(13) || chr(10) || 'ffffffffffffggggggggh' || chr(13) || chr(10) txt from dual union all
 select 'row3' rowval, 'ii' || chr(13) || chr(10) || 'jjjjjjjjjjkkk' || chr(13) || chr(10) txt from dual
)
select rowval,
       txt
  from (select rowval,
               trim(regexp_substr(txt, '[^' || CHR(13)||CHR(10) || ']+', 1, lines.column_value)) txt
          from (select rowval,
                       regexp_replace(txt,
                                      '(.{10})',
                                      '\1' || CHR(13) || CHR(10)) txt
                  from (SELECT rowval,
                               trim(regexp_substr(data.txt, '[^' || CHR(13)||CHR(10) || ']+', 1, lines.column_value)) txt
                          FROM data,
                               TABLE(CAST(MULTISET(SELECT LEVEL
                                                     FROM dual
                                                   CONNECT BY instr(data.txt, CHR(13)||CHR(10), 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
                                                  ) AS sys.odciNumberList
                                         )
                                    ) lines
                        ) data2
               ) data3,
               TABLE(CAST(MULTISET(SELECT LEVEL
                                             FROM dual
                                           CONNECT BY instr(data3.txt, CHR(13)||CHR(10), 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
                                          ) AS sys.odciNumberList
                                 )
                         ) lines
       ) data4
 where txt is not null
ORDER BY rowval, txt;
```

This query yields us:

```
ROWV TXT
---- ------------
row1 aaaaaa
row1 aaaaaaaaaa
row1 aaaaaaaaaa
row1 bb
row1 bbbbbbbbbb
row1 bbbbbbbbbb
row1 bbbbbbbbbb
row1 ccccc
row1 cccccccccc
row1 ddddd
row2 eeee
row2 ffffffffff
row2 ffgggggggg
row2 h
row3 ii
row3 jjjjjjjjjj
row3 kkk
```

Comment: ```
!listofnames@yahoo.com! AbsentCRLFJANEDOECRLF7001044CRLF_ MELT SHOPCRLFPhone: 555-555-5555CRLFSupervisor: JANEDOECRLFEmployee Calling: YesCRLFShift Type: RegularCRLFPersonal Day: YesCRLFShift: DaysCRLFReason: SickCRLF1st Day
```

I have a column which splits data using CLRF, I am using Oracle Sql Developer 11g. How do I split this string into multiple columns?

This is what I have so far

```
SELECT 
    regexp_substr("MESSAGE_TXT",  '[^ ]+')
FROM TABLE WHERE number = 123
```