# multiple selection in single query oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE TABLE CENSUS_MSA_DROPDOWN (
  OID  number(15),
  CityName  VARCHAR(60) CONSTRAINT census_msa_dropdown_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  StateCode CHAR(2));


select OID,SUBSTR(Basename,1, INSTR(Basename,',',1)-1),
substr(basename,LENGTH(basename)-1,2)
from CENSUS_MSA;
```

result:

263904755925760 Anaheim-Santa Ana-Irvine    CA

So how can I separate each city in one line with use multiple selection 
like :   Anaheim  CA
         Santa Ana CA
         Irvine   CA

Comment: Well, splitting up the string by hyphens can be done; and in this case they are all in one state so you could then slap the state on the end of each substring from the name.  But what would you do with "Fayetteville-Springdale-Rogers, AR-MO" - three city names but only two states?  Which state goes with which city?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407538/split-string-into-rows-oracle-sql gives an idea of how to do the strip splitting

Comment: my question is how do we separate each city for each state in a single line using substring and multiple select query?

Answer (score 1):

According to your sample data and desired output, in fact you want to extract values between `-` in a string like `Anaheim-Santa Ana-Irvine` and then join them with a value like `CA` so the result as you mentioned should be:

```
Anaheim   CA
Santa Ana CA
Irvine    CA
```

Using `regx_substr` for such these scenarios is very useful, you can achive the result by cross joining the extracted values with a generated list(table) of ids with count of number of values in the complex string:

```
SQL> create table strTable(complexStr varchar(100),strId varchar(5));

Table created.

SQL> insert into strTable values('Anaheim-Santa Ana-Irvine','CA');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select trim(regexp_substr(t.complexStr, '[^-]+', 1, ids.column_value)) city,
  2  t.strId state
  3  from strTable t
  4  cross join
  5  table (cast (multiset
  6  (select level from dual connect by level <= regexp_count(t.complexStr, '-')+1)
  7  AS sys.odciNumberList)) ids;

CITY        STATE
--------------------   
Anaheim     CA

Santa Ana   CA

Irvine      CA


SQL> drop table strTable;

Table dropped.

SQL>
```