# Search a group of substrings from string and display all the records

Tags: sql, plsql, many-to-many, plsqldeveloper

I am using Oracle 11g.

I am storing multiple values in a column separated by delimiter(#@#). I know it is wrong database design but since it is used for many years i can't do much about it.
I need to perform a search operation where i pass multiple values and i should get all the records if any one value match within the stored value. I read about regular expressions for such scenarios.
Can someone guide me how to proceed with this? Thanks in advance.

Thanks

Comment: can you give us some sample data and table layouts? if you can I would prefer it if you could put it in a http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: in MSSQL if i know a max number of possible search terms I wld use `WHERE (Col LIKE '%#@#'+SearchTerm1 +'#@#%' OR SearchTerm1 Is NULL) AND (Col LIKE '%#@#'+SearchTerm2 +'#@#%' OR SearchTerm2 Is NULL)...` .. for unknown numbers of search terms then i would populate a temp table jand join to it.. `SELECT * FROM YourTable AS A INNER JOIN #STerms AS B on A.Col LIKE '%#@#'+B.STerm+'#@#%'` ..

Comment: note my answer is making assumptions about how you have used delimiters.. e.g. if you don't use delimiters when you have only one value then you need to think about how you want to handle the various scenarios as they will all have their weaknesses depending on what values you are storing there.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9273b/1/0

Please refer this link... I am expecting all the records where Portfolio1 is there.

Comment: maybe i'm not understanding what you are trying to do but can't you just query with like? select * from projects
where portfolio like '%Portfolio1%'

Comment: I have to use it in where clause of the query. And also multiple values will be passed as search string.

Answer (score 0):

Modification of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407538/split-string-into-rows-oracle-sql):

```
WITH tab AS (SELECT 'ab#@#bc#@#cd#@#de#@#ef' col FROM DUAL)
SELECT subcol
  FROM (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (col,
                                  '[^#@#]+',
                                  1,
                                  LEVEL)
                      subcol
              FROM tab
        CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (col,
                                  '[^#@#]+',
                                  1,
                                  LEVEL)
                      IS NOT NULL)
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (subcol, 'c|d');
```

The inner select builds a table of all values separated by #@#. In your app you build the search term list with '|' as separator and pass it eg. like a [bind variable](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_cursor.htm#TGSQL848).

Comment: I have added few more rows in the table for testing. I am not sure whether i am searching in right way. Please have a look at this sqlfiddle demo:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a27058/2

Comment: I have made a new version at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73094/10. Have added a distinct and a lower() to serve what seems to be your needs. You will have to test it thoroughly if you need it in production though.