# Can we define a variable which contains the range of values in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, range

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5653423/383688) I've found how to define a variable in Oracle SQL Developer.

But can we define the range of values somehow?

I need smth like this:

```
define my_range = '55 57 59 61 67 122'; 
delete from ITEMS where ITEM_ID in (&&my_range);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WHERE IN condition not accepting String value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648999/where-in-condition-not-accepting-string-value)

Comment: Don't know oracle's abilities to deal with XML, but you might use an XML parameter like `<root><prm value="55"/><prm value="57"/> [...] </root>` In SQL Server it was very easy to get a derived table with `.nodes()`

Comment: @MT0 Nope. My question is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually if you put commas in your list it will work since you are using a substitution parameter (not a bind variable):

```
define my_range = '55, 57, 59, 61, 67, 122'; 
delete from ITEMS where ITEM_ID in (&&my_range);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use a collection:

```
CREATE TYPE INT_TABLE AS TABLE OF INT;
/
```

Then you can do:

```
DEFINE my_range = '55,57,59,61,67,122';
DELETE FROM   items
WHERE  ITEM_ID MEMBER OF INT_TABLE( &&my_range );
```

**Example**:

```
CREATE TABLE ITEMS ( ITEM_ID ) AS
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 150;

DEFINE my_range = '55,57,59,61,67,122';
DELETE FROM items WHERE ITEM_ID MEMBER OF INT_TABLE( &&my_range );
```

**Output**:

```
Table ITEMS created.

old:DELETE FROM items WHERE ITEM_ID MEMBER OF INT_TABLE( &&my_range );
new:DELETE FROM items WHERE ITEM_ID MEMBER OF INT_TABLE( 55,57,59,61,67,122 );

6 rows deleted.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIKE and just change the way you contain your variable.. Something like this:

```
define my_range = ',55,57,59,61,67,122,'; 
delete from ITEMS
where $$my_range like ('%,' || ITEM_ID || ',%');
```

Comment: Maybe just the following should work: `define my_range = '55,57,59,61,67,122'; delete from ITEMS where ITEM_ID in (&&my_range);`?