# How to get uniqe values of a varchar variable in oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can I get unique values of a varchar variable in oracle pl/sql?
I have a variable like this:

```
aa;bb;aa;cc;dd;ee;dd
```

I would like to get the unique values still separated by ";".
Desired result:

```
aa;bb;cc;dd;ee
```

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: While this is possible, it's really not desirable at all to store your data in CSV (SSV, semicolon separated values) format, because it renders your database impotent to help you query results.  So I vote for changing your database design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first [split your string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407538/split-string-into-rows-oracle-sql), use `DISTINCT` to filter duplicates and combine it again using [`LISTAGG`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) (example at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/18429)).

```
SELECT LISTAGG(x, ';') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY x)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT regexp_substr('aa;bb;aa;cc;dd;ee;dd', '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) AS x
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY regexp_substr('aa;bb;aa;cc;dd;ee;dd', '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
);
```

This returns
`aa;bb;cc;dd;ee`

Answer (score 1):

In case of oracle 11g and greater you can use this

```
SELECT listagg(val,';') WITHin GROUP(ORDER BY NULL) 
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR('aa;bb;aa;cc;dd;ee;dd', '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) val
   FROM dual
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('aa;bb;aa;cc;dd;ee;dd', '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

And xmlquery.

```
select xmlcast( xmlquery('let $i  := string-join(distinct-values(ora:tokenize($doc,";")),";") return  $i' passing 'aa;bb;aa;cc;dd;ee;dd' as "doc" returning content) as varchar2(4000)) from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can easily achieve this by using REGEXP and WMSYS.WM_CONCAT(even
>   though its undocumented function ) or LISTAGG to chive this. Please
>   see below snippet. Hope this helps.

```
SELECT wm_concat(DISTINCT regexp_substr('aa;bb;aa;cc;dd;ee;dd','[^;]+', 1, level))
FROM dual
  CONNECT BY regexp_substr('aa;bb;aa;cc;dd;ee;dd', '[^;]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Please don't use wm_concat. It only supports comma as a delimiter whereas OP wants a semicolon. It is an undocumented function that is only used by oracle [internally](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1336219.1). And most of all, it is discontinued in 12c.