# creating table of varchar dynamically

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to create a table of varChar to format a string
(basically I'm trying to do a cheater `split()` function).

so if I do

```
type tableOfStrings is table of varchar2(50);
vWords tableOfStrings := tableOfStrings ('a','few','words');
dbms_output.put_line(vwords.count); -- 3
```

but if I try

```
type tableOfStrings  is table of varchar2(50);
vTemp varchar(300) := '''a'',''few'',''words''';
vWords tableOfStrings := tableOfStrings (vTemp);
dbms_output.put_line(vwords.count); -- 1 (it's a single string 'a','few','words')
```

I'd like to pass a string to a function and have each word added to the table.

Something like

```
FUNCTION FLABELFORMAT(pMyString in varchar2) return varchar2

type tableOfStrings  is table of varchar2(50);
vWords tableOfStrings := tableOfStrings (pMyString);

for i in 1 .. vWords.count loop
    {do some cool stuff}
end loop;
END FLABELFORMAT
```

How can I accomplish using something like `vWords tableOfStrings := tableOfStrings (pMyString);` and have it add each value to the table?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407538/split-string-into-rows-oracle-sql), try this:

```
SELECT regexp_substr('a,few,words', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
FROM dual
CONNECT BY regexp_substr('a,few,words', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Not as "simple" as i was hoping for but it works. thanks.